# On click of listview item I am trying to retrieve corresponding child values from the firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I have a listview that shows one value from my firebase 'title'. 'title' is a child of 'locs'. The 'locs' have more than one child namely 'latitude' 'longitude' 'address' etc.. Each title have different latitude longitude etc.. On click of the listview item I need to retrieve the latitude and longitude respective to that 'title'

here is my firebase json

```
 "locs" : {
        "-Ld1umasdRJ7R_UwVHpf" : {
          "addr" : "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
          "lati" : "33.xxxxxxxxxx",
          "longi" : "44.xxxxxxxxxx",
          "title" : "Marriage"
        },
        "-Ld2hDcmbt7bAy6eTi7w" : {
          "addr" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          "lati" : "11.xxxxxxxxxxxx",
          "longi" : "22.xxxxxxxxxxx",
          "title" : "Get apple"
        },
```

So example if I press listview item 'Get Apple' I need to get only the values 11.xxxxxxxxxx and 22.xxxxxxxxxxx.

My listview code

```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    mDatabase.child("users").child(mUserId).child("locs").orderByChild("title")
              .equalTo(listView.getItemIdAtPosition(position))
              .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
              @Override
          public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                  }
               }

             @Override
          public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
              });
        Intent i = new Intent(Location.this,GeoFenceActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("radius",val);
        startActivity(i);
                }
            });
```

I have no idea how to proceed next. I tried some methods but in all cases I am getting null values instead of latitude and longitude. I am new to this whole firebase thing.

Comment: Please read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it will really help you get answers. A few things to change here: 1) Replace `listView.getItemIdAtPosition(position)` with a hard-coded value with which you can reproduce the problem, 2) Do something with the data in `onDataChange` that doesn't. Simplest is usually logging something from the data, and then showing what shows up in Logcat for it, and what you expected to get.

Comment: Please do what Frank van Puffelen has instructed you to do and tell us the result.